# Pandas: concat multiple dicts to a single dataframe with values as columns and inner keys as sub columns

Tags: pandas, dataframe, dictionary, concatenation

I have a stream of messages produced by Kafka and I'm in need to create mini-batches based of the content on the messages.

Well, to make it simple, consider the empty dataframe below:

```
import pandas as pd

dict1 = {
    "exchange": "binance",
    "base": "kp3r",
    "quote": "busd",
    "resolution": 15,
    "ohlcv": [
        {
            "source_id": 7905,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-05T14:45:00.000Z",
            "open": "131.5500000000000000",
            "high": "131.8400000000000000",
            "low": "130.3800000000000000",
            "close": "130.9400000000000000",
            "volume": "90.2900000000000000"
        }]
}

dict2 = {
    "exchange": "kucoin",
    "base": "mln",
    "quote": "usdt",
    "resolution": 15,
    "ohlcv": [
        {
            "source_id": 19252,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-05T13:00:00.000Z",
            "open": "24.5610000000000000",
            "high": "24.5610000000000000",
            "low": "24.5610000000000000",
            "close": "24.5610000000000000",
            "volume": "0.0000000000000000"
        }]
}

df_cols = ["_".join(list(dict1.values())[1:-2]), "_".join(list(dict2.values())[1:-2])]
df_sub_cols = list(dict1['ohlcv'][0].keys())[:-1]

print(df_cols)

print(df_sub_cols)

mux = pd.MultiIndex.from_product([df_cols, df_sub_cols])
df = pd.DataFrame(columns=mux)

print(df)
```

How can we fill this dataframe with corresponding values given in dictionaries above?

Comment: Do you need the keys in ohlcv as a subtable or as a column in the main table?

Comment: As sub columns in the main table. @HimanshuPoddar

Comment: okay, wait a jiffy I am providing a slution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution using pandas `explode`, `pop` and `set_index`.

For the `data dict` you have only one data in the `ohlcv` list. Hence you won't be able to visualize the data properly. I have added some more values to your list `ohlcv` so that its easier to visualize the resultant dataframe.

Lets say both your data is present in a list.

```
data_dict = [{
    "exchange": "binance",
    "base": "kp3r",
    "quote": "busd",
    "resolution": 15,
    "ohlcv": [
        {
            "source_id": 7905,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-05T14:45:00.000Z",
            "open": "131.55",
            "high": "131.84",
            "low": "130.38",
            "close": "130.94",
            "volume": "90.29"
        },
        {
            "source_id": 7905,
            "timestamp": "2021-07-05T08:35:00.000Z",
            "open": "169.55",
            "high": "125.84",
            "low": "136.38",
            "close": "126.94",
            "volume": "900.29"
        },
        {
            "source_id": 19252,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-05T13:00:00.000Z",
            "open": "24.5610000000000000",
            "high": "24.5610000000000000",
            "low": "24.5610000000000000",
            "close": "24.5610000000000000",
            "volume": "0.0000000000000000"
        }]
    },
    {
    "exchange": "kucoin",
    "base": "mln",
    "quote": "usdt",
    "resolution": 15,
    "ohlcv": [
        {
            "source_id": 19252,
            "timestamp": "2022-07-05T13:00:00.000Z",
            "open": "24.56",
            "high": "24.56",
            "low": "24.56",
            "close": "24.56",
            "volume": "0.0"
        }]
    }
]
```

The two values in data_dict list will be read as 2 rows with pd.DataFrame, using explode to duplicate the rows `"exchange","base", "quote", "resolution"` for each value in the list `ohlcv`

```
df = pd.DataFrame(data_dict).explode("ohlcv")
```

This gives us

[image]

Now we would like to read dictionary from `ohlcv` and convert the keys to columns.

```
df = df.pop("ohlcv").apply(pd.Series)
```

This gives us

[image]

We would like the resultant table after exploding to join the main dataframe and join corresponding values by the same index.

```
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("ohlcv").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
```

This gives us

[image]

Now we would like duplicated values in `"exchange","base", "quote", "resolution"` to occur only once, we can set them as index values. The values from `"source_id","timestamp","open","high","low","close","volume"` should be retained.

```
df = df.set_index(["exchange","base", "quote", "resolution", "source_id"])
```

This gives us the expected output :

[image]

Coming to your code for the 2 dictionaries `dict1` and `dict2`.
All you need to do is :

```
df = pd.DataFrame([dict1, dict2]).explode("ohlcv")
df = pd.concat([df, df.pop("ohlcv").apply(pd.Series)], axis=1)
df = df.set_index(["exchange","base", "quote", "resolution", "source_id"])
```

This gives you :

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer. What about how to pivot the final table such that the result look like this one: https://stackoverflow.com/a/72883659/3436831

Comment: @sci9 I didn't get that question exactly could you ask another one please, specifying the details and I ll answer

Comment: I would be grateful if you could add a final step to this answer to have a table with columns and sub-columns as generated in the question's code. Anyway, your answer is pretty complete. Merci.

Comment: but my code does exactly that `to have a table with columns and sub-columns`

Comment: Your answer is a table with multiple index, so need to be pivoted to get the desired result as generated here https://stackoverflow.com/a/72883659/3436831

Comment: Even that answer is multi Indexed, read the code once!

Comment: yes conceptually has multiple indexes, but pivoted, please see the **OUTPUT** generated.

Comment: If you go for ivot you will loose out on your other columns, `["exchange","base", "quote", "resolution", "source_id"]`